# Python Parsing with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am learning to parse HTML in Python with BeautifulSoup library.I came across a error displaying

```
import urllib

from BeautifulSoup import *

html_doc = """
   <html><head><title>The Dormouse's story</title></head>
   <body>
   <p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>

   <p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and     their names were
   <a href="http://example.com/elsie" class="sister" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
   <a href="http://example.com/lacie" class="sister" id="link2">Lacie</a> and
   <a href="http://example.com/tillie" class="sister" id="link3">Tillie</a>;
   and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>
   <p class="story">...</p>
    """

   soup=BeautifulSoup(html_doc)

   print soup.prettify()

   print soup.title

   print soup.title.name

   print soup.title.string

   print soup.title.parent.name

   print soup.p

   print soup.p['class']

   print soup.a

   print soup.find_all('a')

   #for extracting URL's
   for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        print link.get('href')

  print soup.get_text()
```

Help me fix the above code. I have used Python 2. Below images shows the error[image]

Comment: Include error details or stacktrace from shell

Comment: in current example you have wrong indentions. always show full error message (Traceback) in question. We can run your code without error.

Comment: you should copy-paste error message - it can be more usefull because everyone can copy message and use it in answer or comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't show error message in question so I will guess.

Probably you use old `BeautifulSoup` and you need `findAll()` instead of `find_all()` and `getText()` instead of `get_text()`

---

New `BeautifulSoup` is imported by

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```